# I want to deploy my IERC20 Contract and I need few questions

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, bsc

1. If the contract is using IERC20 can I deploy it on BSC? If yes, should I do something else or simply deploy it via Remix?
2. When I want to deploy my contract I see those options here. What should I choose?

[image]

3. What should I do in order to have those 2 addresses on the "holders" section on BSCscan after I deploy the contract

[image]

4. How do I renounce to ownership? Do I only need to sell all of my coins in order to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see.

1. Should work just fine without modifications
2. You should deploy the lowest-level contract you have. In your case that is probably "Driven (Driven.sol)"
3. That section says who owns your tokens, so who are the token holders. If you want two addresses to hold your tokens, assign or transfer your tokens to those two addresses.
4. You should call the predefined `renounceOwnership` function, which your contract inherits from `Ownable`.

Comment: And the price for my coin will be available after I will add some liquidity through PancakeSwap, right?

Comment: Depends on where & how the price is read - don't really know